# Apache won't start with proxy conf

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy

First of all, thanks for your help. I meet some trouble with apache.

I'm using Ampps, and a custom httpd-vhost2.conf declared in the apache config.

But since i added the last website, it just refuse to start, here is the code :

```
#### www.exemple.com SSL Entries ####

<VirtualHost *:443>
Protocols h2 http/1.1
ServerName www.exemple.com
ServerAlias exemple.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
SSLCertificateFile "/***/www.exemple.com.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/***/www.exemple.com.key"
ErrorLog "/***/www.exemple.com_ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "/***/www.exemple.come_ssl_access.log"
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
Header always set X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$">
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 14 days"
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:4567/$1 [P,L]
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:4567/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:4567/
</VirtualHost>

################################
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had to enable (uncomment) 2 extension in apache config file :

mod_proxy.so and mod_proxy_http.so

Thank you !